# Drupal 7 Commerce Paypal WPP configuration

Tags: drupal, paypal, drupal-7, paypal-sandbox, drupal-modules

I'm trying to configure Drupal 7 commerce paypal module and there seems to be some terminology differences.

The module wants me to fill out:
API Username,
API Password,
Signature

When logged into my PayPal account they give me:
PayPal Account,
Client ID,
Secret

I've put the PayPal account (email address) in the API username field of the commerce paypal module. I've tried the Client ID and Secret in both of the API Password and Signature fields of the module. Unfortunately I'm getting a 10002 error from paypal. Security header is wrong which leads me to believe I'm not authenticating with PayPal.

If you can imagine, PayPal support hasn't been much help. I'm wondering if there's a place in my paypal account that has different information that I don't see or if Paypal changed their service and it no longer works with the commerce paypal module for Drupal 7.

Anyone have any thoughts?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

ClientID and Secret are used by all the current REST APIs.

API Username, Password, and Signature (or Certificate) are used by the old Classic NVP/SOAP APIs.  You can get this information from your account via https://www.paypal.com/api

Payments Pro is an old API for a premium gateway-like service--to use it, you need to apply and be approved for that Pro service https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/paypal-payments-pro

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. The link and mention of NVP/SOAP solved my problem. Now if I can only get PayPal support to be half as good.